# Codename One: Invoke codename code from native interface

Tags: codenameone, publish-subscribe

I am writing a real time library for Codename one by wrapping the native libraries of Ably. I am invoking native interfaces to include the libraries for each platform, but how can I call Codename one code from the native interface or emit an event? For example, if I subscribe from an iOS client, how can tell the normal Codename One code that a message has been received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [advanced section of the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_native_interfaces) look for the section titled "Native Code Callbacks".

This is pretty challenging as it differs between platforms so it's recommended to keep the callback to a minimum when possible.

Comment: There are instructions for Java platforms, iOS and Javascript. Is there a way to use it from windows phone?

Comment: The Windows Phone port is on the way out. If you are referring to UWP then we should probably add those too. I'll ask Steve to look into it.